# Django query for items that have a unique field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an Item model, and there is a manyToOne with Items and Users (multiple items per User). I would like to make a query for items but not get any items with the same user twice. For example if I had users with items:

```
John
  iPhone
  macbook
  mousepad

Elaine
  PC
  Battery

Jane
  TV
  Cabinet
```

I would like to make an Item query and get back iPhone, PC, TV or macbook, PC, Cabinet, or whatever combination, as long as each item has a unique user. Is there a way to do this with django and SQL? Or do I have to do this on the python level? maybe something like:

```
items = Item.objects.all()
items = items.filter(user__isunique=True) #This doesn't work. I tried it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
Item.objects.filter(your_filter).distinct('user') #or Item.objects.distinct('user')
```

if your model is like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   # ...
```

be careful though if you want to [order_by with distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)